# How to enable apex class and trigger in Salesforce professional edition?

Tags: community

I have Salesforce professional edition. In this edition I am not able to find and enable API's and APEX classes and triggers.

Can anyone tell me how can I enable these feature? Is there need to contact Salesforce support?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce professional edition does not support Apex & VF, API and many other features. Last time we get the quote for enabling one of our customer and price was almost equal to Enterprise Edition. The best way to find exact cost is to get in touch with your SF account executive. Once the costing is final support can enable it for you but not before that.

Comment: Thank you Atul. I have enabled API's in professional edition through SF Executive. Is APEX comes with this activation? Or I need to make another request?

Comment: I think you will need another request

Comment: Hi I have enabled apex in salesforce professional edition but there is no option to create new apex class or trigger. Can you say me how can I do this?